# jQuery Validate plugin v1.10 validating (requiring) all inputs in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the current version of jQuery (1.8.3) and the latest version of jQuery validate (1.10.0), and it seems that in Internet Explorer 8, jquery validate is validating all the inputs on the form being validated, not just those with defined rules. It works just fine in other browsers (IE9+, FF, Chrome), and it works fine if I use jQuery validate 1.9.0.

Here is an example that demonstrates the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>IE8 + jQuery Validate 1.10 Test</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="my-form">
            <label for="my-required-field">required:</label>
            <input id="my-required-field" type="text" name="reqField" />
            <label for="my-optional-field">optional:</label>
            <input id="my-optional-field" type="text" name="optField" />
            <input id="wh-submit-button" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var form = $("#my-form");
            var validator = form.validate({
                rules: {
                    "reqField": { required: true }
                },
                messages: {
                    "reqField": { required: "this field is <i>actually</i> required" }
                }
            });

            $("#wh-submit-button").click(function () {
                if (validator.form()) {
                    alert('passed validation');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In IE8, the "passed validation" alert won't fire, and the optional field will be marked as required.

If I explicitly mark the optional field as not required, it does work correctly:

```
rules: {
    "reqField": { required: true },
    "optField": { required: false }
}
```

However, it's certainly suboptimal to have to mark every input element that isn't required explicitly as optional, and that has never been a previous requirement, as far as I know.

I know that there were issues with earlier versions of jquery and jquery validate, but they were ostensibly resolved with jQuery validate 1.8.1 - I'm raising this issue since it seems to be with the latest versions of jquery and the validate plugin.

UPDATE:

So, the issue appears only to manifest itself when using the Internet Explorer F12 developer tools to emulate IE8 behavior. Based on the comment suggesting that there was no actual issue with the sample I provided in IE8, I built out a complete Windows VM with a true Internet Explorer 8 installation, and, in fact, there was no issue. Though there are obviously differences between an emulator and the real thing, I had never seen such an issue with the JavaScript emulation before, and was thrown by the fact that it suddenly started happening with jQuery Validation 1.10.

Since it's only an issue with the emulation, not the real thing, there is nothing to solve here; and I should have disclosed that it was via the emulator in the first place... but perhaps someone else will fall into the same trap and this will be a useful reference.

Comment: code works fine for me in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/BGDfr/1/

Comment: not sure why you using submit button click handler to call `form()` might consider using `submitHandler` callback insted

Comment: What @charlietfl said.  The `validate()` plugin already has a `submitHandler:` built in for this.  By using your own click handler, you are reinitializing the plugin on the form unnecessarily.  I've seen many situations where this causes all kinds of weird issues like having to click the button twice, etc.

Comment: FYI:  There is no such thing as an "IE8 emulator" within F12 in any IE browser.  That is called "compatibility mode" and it was meant as a fall-back for webpages with out-of-date code.  At least once a week here I'm helping on a question where somebody finds what they think is a huge problem in IE 7 or 8, that turns out to only be a compatibility mode issue... so don't feel too bad.

Comment: Thanks for this reference, i fell in the same trap and this saved me time!

Comment: We're using jQuery Validation 1.11.1.  A designer added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">` to fix some IE9-specific rendering problems. As a result, IE10 treated every field as "required".  After adding some server-side logic to prevent the output of the metatag for non-IE9 browsers, the problem was immediately fixed in IE10.

Comment: I also was having this problem, glad to know it's just the emulator. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

**[jsFiddle DEMO using built-in jQuery 1.8.2](http://jsfiddle.net/ncLsy/)**

**[jsFiddle DEMO using jQuery 1.8.3](http://jsfiddle.net/ncLsy/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var form = $("#my-form");
    var validator = form.validate({
        rules: {
            "reqField": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "reqField": {
                required: "this field is <i>actually</i> required"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('passed validation');
            // form.submit();
        }
    });

});​
```

Comment: It appears to make no difference whether or not submitHandler is used - it fails equally in the emulator, and succeeds equally in a true IE8. I don't follow the point re-initializing the plugin when not using submitHandler (the point from your comment above). In any case, my "actual" case does not submit the form - I just need to test its validity before taking another action... so, I think submitHandler is not quite the right convenience method.

Comment: @KentMcNeill, If you just need to test validity of the form, that's what `.valid()` method is for.  `if (form.valid())`, etc.  Of course, if you're testing validity upon clicking the actual `submit` button, that's what `submitHandler:` is for, since it only fires upon validity.  And every time you call `.validate()`, you reinitialize the validation on the form... again, like I explained, I've seen plenty of weird issues reported here that are caused by this poor practice.  Just search my posted/accepted answers to see at least half a dozen.